# VBA: Dynamic range count function

Tags: excel, dynamic, count, range, vba

I want to get this table:

```
 C|O     1       2       3      Count
 A       1       1       0       2
 B       0       0       1       1
 C       0       0       0       0
```

However, with the code I have been developing I get the following result. The number of columns and rows are dynamic.

```
 C|O     1       2       3      Count
 A       1       1       0       2
 B       
 C
```

Here's the code. I think the first problem is on the countRange. And the second problem is when I put the count value, I want to do as initial values b = 0 and k = 1 as well I want to advance a = a + 1 and repeat the While cycle.

```
Dim a As Integer
a = 0
Dim b As Integer
b = 0
Dim k As Integer
k = 1
operations = 1

 Do While operations <= sh1.Range("D4").Value + 1
  If sh2.Cells(12,3+b) = "Count" Then
   Dim countRange As Range
   Set countRange = sh2.Range(Cells(13+a, 3),Cells(13+a,3+b-1))
   Dim count As Integer
   count = sh2.Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(countRange)
   sh2.Cells(13+a,3+b) = count
   a = a + 1
   b = 0
   k = 1
  Else
   If sh2.Cells(12+a,3+b) = operations Then
    If sh2.Cells(13+a,2) = arrayC(k) Then
     sh2.Cells(13+a,3+b).Value = 1
    Else
     sh2.Cells(13+a,3+b).Value = 0
    End If
   End If
   operations = operations + 1
   b = b + 1
   k = k + 1
  End If
 Wend
```

Comment: The code above does not run - `Do` / `Wend` aren't matching ends of a loop.  Please update the question to include the latest version of your code.  It would also be good to include in the question some indication of what the `arrayC` variable is, what rows and columns your sample data is in, what cell D4 on worksheet `sh1` contains, and maybe even what it is that you are trying to calculate.

Comment: It would be quite helpful if you proved a screen-shot of your original data set-uo in sheet, the original setup you are trying to run this code

Answer (score 0):

Declare the `operations` variable as `Dim operations as Integer = 1` and use while loop. the Do....While loop surely executes at least for single time.

Comment: The operations As Integer is defined above in other part of code. I don't think it is required to declare the variable again.